# Xcode Console junk

Tags: xcode

The Xcode console has started to show a list like this

```
  BRANCH(
 :BRANCH...
 :OPEN2(
 :OPEN2...
 :BRANCH(
 :BRANCH...
 :PLUS...
 :OPEN3(
```

along with some of NSLog.

What are these and how can I get rid of them.

Comment: Did they come out of nowhere? What were you running?

Comment: This is with Xcode 4.6.2 I was debugging my app and these started showing up in the middle of the NSLog messages.

Comment: And you're sure that this junk isn't part of your app?

Comment: Yes, I am sure these are not part of the code, unless they could be embedded in the jpg I am using as buttons.